# RabbitMQ Consumer not working

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, ssl, rabbitmq, message-queue

I am using RabbitMq in my symfony app, The Producer is successfully sent messages to rabbitmq but somehow consumer is not working.

I run below command,

```
sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues messages name
Listing queues ...
2014 notification.notification.create
```

I have both test and prod server, Initially error was Signature verification issue, So i regenerate signautre and resinstall rabbitmq on Test server. It was solved. then i tried same on prod server but it didn't work.

I see there are two logs files in /var/log/rabbitmq `ssl.log` and `test.log`

```
tail -f test.log

accepting AMQP connection <0.10580.12> (127.0.0.1:53668 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Feb-2017::08:59:00 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.10580.12> (127.0.0.1:53668 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Feb-2017::12:29:07 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.14663.15> (127.0.0.1:38318 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Feb-2017::12:29:07 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.14663.15> (127.0.0.1:38318 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

and tail -f ssl.log

Supervisor: {<0.542.0>,rabbit_channel_sup_sup}
     Context:    shutdown_error
     Reason:     shutdown
     Offender:   [{nb_children,1},
                  {name,channel_sup},
                  {mfargs,{rabbit_channel_sup,start_link,[]}},
                  {restart_type,temporary},
                  {shutdown,infinity},
                  {child_type,supervisor}]
```

Comment: I would expect to see a bit of relevant symfony code of your app after reading "I am using RabbitMq in my symfony app"!

Comment: @BentCoder you thing problem is the symfony app? same app is deployed on test server and working fine there.

Comment: Go to http://www.inanzzz.com/ and search for `RabbitMq` keyword which will give you plenty of RabbitMQ+Symfony examples. It might be helpful for you.

Comment: I am using this bundle https://packagist.org/packages/php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle, I run this `$ php app/console rabbitmq:consumer old_sound_rabbit_mq.notification_create_consumer` & got error `[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]You have requested a non-existent service "old_sound_rabbit_mq.old_sound_rabbit_mq.notification_create_consumer_consumer".`